# WooCommerce Stripe payment plugin working perfectly in storefront parent theme but not in the child theme

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I've created a child theme out of the Storefront theme. Everything seems to be working fine but on the checkout page, there is a WooCommerce Stripe payment plugin that is working perfectly fine in the parent theme itself but when I use the child theme, that plugin fails to load properly. The credit card fields are looking weird as well as I am unable to put anything in the fields. (screenshot attached). When I inspected through Chrome inspect tool, the fields are not populating at all in the DOM.

Is there anything I need to add in my function file etc?. Since in parent Storefront theme it's working like a charm.

Kindly help me out since I am very new to WP theme development.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your child theme is not setup properly.
I would recommend asking the theme developer on how to create a child theme. Or use a plugin to create a child theme for you. There are several child theme creator plugins.

In addition to that you will need to ensure that all server caching and all caching plugins have been disabled as those can cause issues when switching to child themes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've created the child theme exactly mentioned in the codex. Even I don't have any cache plugin installed. I would definitely give a try to child theme creator plugins.